# flowtype: How to take over generic type with inner function?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

i'm using flowtype.
i guess the following two codes are the same, but the above code gives an error.

What's the difference in the following two codes?
and how to use generic `T` type in `getMergedState` function's arguments without specifying like `getMergedState<State>`

it gets an error:
(property `foo` is missing in `T` but exists in object literal)

```
type State = {| foo: string, bar: string |}

function getState<T>(initialState: T) {
  const getMergedState = (prevState: T, newState: $Shape<T>): T => ({
    ...prevState,
    ...newState
  });
  return [state, getMergedState];
}
const [state, getMergedState] = getState<State>({ foo: '1', bar: '2' });
const newState = getMergedState(state, { foo: '2' });
```

it works:

```
type State = {| foo: string, bar: string |}

function getState<T>(initialState: T) {
  const getMergedState = <K>(prevState: K, newState: $Shape<K>): K => ({
   ...prevState,
   ...newState
  });
  return [state, getMergedState];
}
const [state, getMergedState] = getState<State>({ foo: '1', bar: '2' });
const newState = getMergedState<State>(state, { foo: '2' });
```

[try flow](https://flow.org/try/#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)

**EDIT:**
i simplified the code to show the flow's link, but made some mistakes.

original code:

```
function useMergeState<T>(initialState: T) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<T>(initialState);
  const setMergedState = (newState: $Shape<T>) =>
    setState((prevState: T) => ({ ...prevState, ...newState }));
  return [state, setMergedState];
}

type State = {|
  text: ?string,
  text2: ?string
|};

const getInitialState = (): State => {
  return {
    text: null,
    text2: null
  };
};

const Example = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useMergeState<State>(getInitialState());
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={state.text}
        onChange={event => {
          setState({ text: event.target.value });
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is `state` in the `return` statement of `getState` coming from? Is `initialState` supposed to be used anywhere?

Comment: @user11307804 sorry, i added the original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got everything to typecheck with the following code on v0.116.0:

```js
import * as React from "react";

function useMergeState<T: {}>(initialState: T): [T, $Shape<T> => void] {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<T>(initialState);
  const setMergedState = (newState: $Shape<T>) =>
    setState((prevState: T): T => ({ ...prevState, ...newState }));
  return [state, setMergedState];
}

type State = {|
  text: ?string,
  text2: ?string
|};

const getInitialState = (): State => {
  return {
    text: null,
    text2: null
  };
};

const Example = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useMergeState<State>(getInitialState());
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={state.text}
        onChange={event => {
          setState({ text: event.target.value });
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdBArgHb7AQtxOpYCyWKAHMsAZRjIYWADwAVAFxwA3gF8AfAApgLYDGDIANuMlZFsgJSKA2rIA0cACSiAFsjAzZauAF4vANwhgABMAXWU6ODhcTlR4K1iTe14YYykw70wqGAA6HjEJKTlNbV19IwKsc3pI6JZYuGSBYSwg1KwfOA0WLAB3NsUnV3ci8x81CMiGrBSKjQ0wSj9+uAszMc6lOGzthawlivtt7O6+irgVcyqJyhgmKC54g6mYJpFWipD6FQYYAE93OBtDpKAA+EykAA8YIoAPyxKDaIS2cFYKEAJlh8MRdBBKnodFq9REMAAkjo9IYgRkNJZAWdfOFIjc7lwlBNIpDoXAWEwDAZkZM4JyMdzeQYJni6JKCTF4ABRCHIcAGdrU0YMtk1WVwR6JZ5tdLcXivfImaRtTTEsmlSmzS7VODM+6ddlwaQEaAgcaCyLSbRgJgwV2CvyGJhYbxKBJSbKc74+yacADCrhYIkjeywLHgGuDPuSbQ0m05ikz2djyGaOVDBnD5yuCciKnjPoA9N7JtJWx6oF6Jlc8UA)

The main changes were subtyping `T` as an object (`T: {}`), specifying the return type of `useMergeState` (`[T, $Shape<T> => void]`), and specifying the return type of `setState` in `useMergeState` (`T`). (I also added the import from react for Try Flow.) The code will error if you call `setState` with properties that do not appear in the `State` type definition, or if the value types are not appropriate (e.g., you set a number as the value of `text`).